# mysql: not able to create join based on closest timestamp

Tags: mysql, join, closest, sql-timestamp

i read multiple threads in this great community but somehow i could not get my problem solved.

I have two tables:

Table A.

```
id    timestamp               value
1     2018-03-30 00:01:00     100
2     2018-03-30 00:02:02     200
3     2018-03-30 00:03:01     300
4     2018-03-30 00:03:59     400
5     2018-03-30 00:05:00     500
6     2018-03-30 00:06:07     600
7     2018-03-30 00:06:54     700
8     2018-03-30 00:08:00     800
```

Table B:

```
id    timestamp               value
1     2018-03-30 00:00:59     10
2     2018-03-30 00:01:12     20
3     2018-03-30 00:01:20     30
4     2018-03-30 00:01:25     40
5     2018-03-30 00:01:40     50
6     2018-03-30 00:02:01     60
7     2018-03-30 00:02:05     70
8     2018-03-30 00:02:09     80
```

I'm trying to create a statement to join my tables. and to calculate with the values.

Target table:

```
timestamp               a.value    b.value   diff
2018-03-30 00:01:00     100        10        90
2018-03-30 00:02:02     200        60        140
```

the callenge for me is, to get the clostest time value to do the join.

Current approach, based on another tread here:

```
SELECT 
a.`id`,
a.`timestamp`,
(SELECT b.`timestamp`
FROM `databaseB`.`tableB` as b
where b.`channel_id`=10 
order by abs(datediff(a.`timestamp`, b.`datetime`)) asc Limit 1) AS newtime,
a.value,
FROM `databaseA`.`tableA` as a;
```

But as a result i recieve only one static value in the column newtime. It is a timestamp, but it is not the right one to create the join.

Can somebody of you see my mistake? What am I doing wrong.

Thx and KR
Holger

Comment: In order to relate rows based on "closest", you would need to determine the "distance" between every row and every other row, the select the lowest "distance". This would be a huge task for the server, but could be optimized by matching on the date part of the timestamp so it only looks at rows on the same day. Joining on the min timestamp greater than a timestamp might get you closer.

Comment: limiting it to a day could lead to problems on a "day change" at 24:00, but limiting it on 5 minutes before and afterwards should be more as enought.

Comment: nobody an idea how to solve this topic?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. You may have to experiment with the intervals in the between statement.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/184ee0/23)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablea`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablea` (
    `id`            INT(11) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `timestamp`     TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `value`         INT(11) UNSIGNED        NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';

INSERT INTO `tablea`
(id,timestamp,value)
VALUES
(1,'2018-03-30 00:01:00',100),
(2,'2018-03-30 00:02:02',200),
(3,'2018-03-30 00:03:01',300),
(4,'2018-03-30 00:03:59',400),
(5,'2018-03-30 00:05:00',500),
(6,'2018-03-30 00:06:07',600),
(7,'2018-03-30 00:06:54',700),
(8,'2018-03-30 00:08:00',800);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableb` (
    `id`            INT(11) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `timestamp`     TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `value`         INT(11) UNSIGNED        NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';

INSERT INTO `tableb`
(id,timestamp,value)
VALUES
(1,'2018-03-30 00:00:59',10),
(2,'2018-03-30 00:01:12',20),
(3,'2018-03-30 00:01:20',30),
(4,'2018-03-30 00:01:25',40),
(5,'2018-03-30 00:01:40',50),
(6,'2018-03-30 00:02:01',60),
(7,'2018-03-30 00:02:05',70),
(8,'2018-03-30 00:02:09',80);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  a.*,
  c.`id`,
  c.`value`,
  a.`value` - c.`value` as `diff`,
  min(b.`timestamp`) as `btimestamp`,
  min(ABS(a.`timestamp` - b.`timestamp`)) as `timediff`
FROM `tablea` a
JOIN `tableb` b
ON b.`timestamp` between 
  date_sub(a.`timestamp`,INTERVAL '0' second) AND 
  date_add(a.`timestamp`,INTERVAL '20' second)
JOIN `tableb` c
ON b.`timestamp` = c.`timestamp`
GROUP BY a.`id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/184ee0/23/0)**:

```
| id |            timestamp | value | id | value | diff |           btimestamp | timediff |
|----|----------------------|-------|----|-------|------|----------------------|----------|
|  1 | 2018-03-30T00:01:00Z |   100 |  2 |    20 |   80 | 2018-03-30T00:01:12Z |       12 |
|  2 | 2018-03-30T00:02:02Z |   200 |  7 |    70 |  130 | 2018-03-30T00:02:05Z |        3 |
```